# Image shows up on every page

Tags: media

I added images to my blog in Drupal 7 and they loaded fine. But one of the images shows up at the bottom of every page of the site. How to I delete it?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: that depends on how you added it. is it loaded manually in a tpl file? is it part of a block set at the bottom (footer?)? do you have any modules installed that automatically add content to the site?

Comment: +1 Please describe the steps how you have added the image! Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Geoff please convert your comment into an answer. so, that you can be awarded.

Comment: @harsh, since my *comment* includes questions and a request for clarification, it's not a proper answer and belongs as a comment as set by the guidelines for Drupal Answers. Please see the Help center for further information